# TensorFlow: TypeError: Expected int64, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead

Tags: tensorflow

My TensorFlow version is 1.0.
When I run the following code:

```
train_file='~/tf_code/train'
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([train_file],num_epochs=None)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, ex = reader.read(filename_queue)

sequence_features = {
    "x":tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype = tf.int64),
    "tomatch_indices_1D":tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype = tf.int64)
}

context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
    serialized=ex,
    context_features={},
    sequence_features=sequence_features
)   

indices = tf.cast(sequence_parsed['tomatch_indices_1D'],tf.int64)
indices = tf.reshape(indices, (-1,3))
x = sequence_parsed['x']
lens = tf.shape(x)[0]
tomatch_sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, tf.ones((tf.shape(indices)[0],)), 
    dense_shape=(lens,lens,lens))
tomatch = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(tomatch_sparse, validate_indices=False)
print(tomatch)
```

Then I got this error on tf.SparseTensor():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/qingping/tf_code/SequenceExample/example_test.py", line 284, in <module>
    stack_test()
  File "/Users/qingping/tf_code/SequenceExample/example_test.py", line 276, in stack_test
    tomatch_sparse = tf.SparseTensor(indices, tf.ones((tf.shape(indices)[0],)), dense_shape=(lens,lens,lens))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py", line 127, in __init__
    dense_shape, name="dense_shape", dtype=dtypes.int64)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 637, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 702, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 110, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 99, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 367, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int64, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

If I want to build SparseTensor by read data(indices) from file, and the dense_shape of SparseTensor is varied, what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this bad error message arises when TensorFlow tries to convert the tuple of `tf.int32` tensors `(lens, lens, lens)` to a single `tf.int64` tensor as the `dense_shape` argument of the `tf.SparseTensor`.

The default return value of [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) is `tf.int32`. You can solve this problem by adding an explicit `out_type` argument when you compute `lens`, as follows:

```
lens = tf.shape(x, out_type=tf.int64)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right! It works well now. before your answer, I store the `dense_shape` in the TFRecord, and then load it to Tensor `dense_shape`.